# How to use @types/bootstrap in my Typescript and React application

Tags: typescript, bootstrap-4

I have an application written in webpack, typescript and react. I added bootstrap to it like

```
yarn add bootstrap @types/bootstrap jquery popper
```

then I wrote a component like

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import * as Bootstrap from 'bootstrap'

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="page-header">Hello</h1>
        <p className="text-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p className="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      </div>  
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Main />,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

but it doesn't seem to be taking any styling from bootstrap.

I googled and there are many many bootstrap tutorials out there. but I can't find a one which shows me how to use bootstrap in a typescript application which uses `@types/bootstrap`

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the `@types/bootstrap` package only contains type definition files for any JavaScript components included with the Bootstrap framework. It shouldn't contain the actual styles or JavaScript components that ship with Bootstrap. To import those, you would additionally need to install the `bootstrap` package.

Comment: I did. I installed bootstrap and @types/bootstrap (see the yarn add command in my question above.). Now how do I apply the styles in my react component.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After few days of trying I was able to resolve this.

This is how you use bootstrap in a react component

Add bootstrap to the typescript project

```
 yarn add bootstrap @types/bootstrap react-bootstrap @types/react-bootstrap -D
```

Now add bootstrap controls to your tsx file like

```
 import {Grid, Row, Col, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
```

Since the css files are not included with the npm you need to link the css manually. I did this in `<HEAD>` section my index.html (the one which contains )

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
```

That's it.

If you are looking for a sample project which uses typescript, react, bootstrap and webpack, then here is an example

https://github.com/abhsrivastava/ts-react-bootstrap

Comment: Or you can link the css like this: <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

Comment: Hi, I am using typescript and bootstrap, I wonder if that still the best way to install bootstrap on the project? it's a Next.js Typescript project.